# Ubuntu 20.04 Server - USB Drive Random Unmount

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, unmount

I have four external usb3 hard drives connected via a usb3 hub to my Ubuntu 20.04 server.
Hardware is an intel core i7-6700T with 8GB ram.

Drives are mounted using fstab and this command:

UUID****    /mnt/add-store   ext4   user,errors=remount-ro,auto,exec,rw,nofail   0    0

Having an issue where any or all of the four drives will randomly disconnect from the mount points and become unavailable.

Commands lsusb, lsblk and lshw all show the drive(s) still connected to the sytem but if I try to manually re-mount the drive(s) which have disconnected using the command "sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/add-store" (as an example), I get the error message "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc, missing codepage or helper program, or other error".

However when I reboot the server, all drives are present and correct when the server is back up.
Drives have no faults or issues that I am aware of.

Very much a Linux beginner so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I did command "sudo cat /var/log/syslog > /file/save/location/syslog | grep usb" and got the syslog from 12am to 8pm (8pm is when command was run).
The messages below are a small sample of what were occurring regularly right from log start to end.

> Sep  2 06:09:26 deep-current rsyslogd: action 'action-12-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]

> Sep  2 06:09:26 deep-current rsyslogd: action 'action-12-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), next retry is Thu Sep  2 06:09:56 2021, retry nbr 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]

> Sep  2 06:09:31 deep-current kernel: [113243.888151] usb 2-4.3: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.

> Sep  2 06:09:31 deep-current kernel: [113243.968828] usb 2-4.3: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd

> Sep  2 06:09:32 deep-current kernel: [113243.993105] scsi host6: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success

> Sep  2 06:10:16 deep-current kernel: [113288.955531] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#26 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN

> Sep  2 06:10:16 deep-current kernel: [113288.955539] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#26 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3e 3f 20 d8 00 01 00 00

> Sep  2 06:10:16 deep-current kernel: [113288.957221] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#25 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN

> Sep  2 06:10:16 deep-current kernel: [113288.957229] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#25 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 3e 3f 1f d8 00 01 00 00

> Sep  2 06:10:16 deep-current kernel: [113288.987486] scsi host6: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start

Comment: When the drives are disconnected there will be a reason recorded in `/var/log/syslog`. Can you [edit] your question to include that reason? This will make it much easier to offer a specific solution to your problem.